# Unicode Support for NSIS (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, unicode, nsis

I am looking for a makensis script that supports unicode but can also run on Ubuntu (linux).

While researching ew came across this project:
https://code.google.com/p/unsis/

But it does not seem to compile on Linux (Windows only)

Currently I am using NSIS 2.46 but it does not have UNICODE support and crashes the installer on run-tim.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the latest official NSIS subversion [trunk](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/) (NSIS 3 Beta), it is known to work on at least some POSIX systems.